# i want to download images with pytelegrambotapi with good quality , but i cant

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to download images with pytelegrambotapi with good quality,
I use this code, its ok and works, but it download images with bad quality.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document', 'photo', 'audio', 'video', 'voice'])
def addfile(message):
    
    if message.photo:
        photo = bot.get_file(message.photo[0].file_id)
        photo_path = photo.file_path
        photo_id = photo.file_id
        photo_type = photo.file_path.split('.')[-1]

        
        file = bot.download_file(photo_path)
        with open(photo_id + "." + photo_type, "wb") as code:
            code.write(file)
```

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sent photo undergoes resizing and compression. If you wish to process the original photo as a file, you may manually send it as a document to the bot or utilize the `sendDocument` feature for that purpose.

Comment: i want the bot receive image and download it with good quality. not document.

Comment: If you want to receive an uncompressed, high-resolution photo without compression, you must send it as a document.

Comment: so how another bots receive images not as a document ?

Comment: @mahdi compression happens before your bot receives anything, thus they just receive the compressed image (it's not necessarily of a bad quality, but not the original)

Comment: thanks for all of your helps. but if you know any way to fix this problem. please tell me.